# tabIndex change using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change a tabindex like this:

```
 document.getElementById('1').tabIndex="3"
 document.getElementById('2').tabIndex="2"
 document.getElementById('3').tabIndex="1"
```

But it's not working, how can I fix it?

Comment: It's possible your code executes before the DOM is fully rendered. What errors are you getting?

Comment: In which browser doesn't it work? Maybe it's because IDs are not allowed to start with numbers...

Comment: actualy i am trying like this in all browsers. document.getElementById('imgSearch').tabeindex = "1";
    document.getElementById('txtAddress1').tabeindex = "2";
    document.getElementById('txtAddress2').tabeindex = "3";
    document.getElementById('txtAddress3').tabeindex = "4";

Comment: there is no error bt not working as i am doing

Comment: What is the HTML of the elements with IDs 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: show your code, please